# How to use condition in cmake generator expression

Tags: cmake

I would like to compile a library as shared or static based on other variable eg:

```
add_library(MyLibrary $<$<IF:${BUILD_SHARED_LIBS},SHARED,STATIC> ${SOURCES})
```

For clarity I expect this to be equivalent with the following:

```
if(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
  add_library(MyLibrary SHARED ${SOURCES})
elseif()
  add_library(MyLibrary STATIC ${SOURCES})
endif()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69346359/3353857,  $<$<STREQUAL:$<TARGET_PROPERTY:Foo,TYPE>,SHARED_LIBRARY>:;$<TARGET_SONAME_FILE:Foo>>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, you cannot do that with [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) (no way to query that aspect according to doc), since [BUILD_SHARED_LIBS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/option.html) is there for exactly that reason; to allow you to select its value during configuration (using the `-D` command line option). This will work only if you do not set the library type explicitly as in your code, but like this

```
add_library(MyLibrary ${SOURCES})
```

Actually, that is the recommended practice. If you need to influence its value in association with some other condition, you can override it with the usual `if()/else()` logic, making sure that you print at least an informative `message()` for the user.

However, an even better approach would be to push those decisions to the user (via [option](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/option.html)s) and check for the illegal combinations, issuing a `message(FATAL_ERROR)`. Even if that condition is determined automatically, this is still a tactic that has merit.